# Как спарсить ссылки на новости? Неверный CSS selector?

Tags: python, lxml, css-selectors

Пытаюсь спарсить ссылки на старые новости из архива сайта https://www.vedomosti.ru/archive/ с помощью css selector. Искал селектор с помощью SelectorGadget для Chrome, показывает что нужный мне имеет вид '.article-preview-item__title', но на выходе пустой лист

Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = 'https://www.vedomosti.ru/archive/2012/10/25'
page = requests.get(url).text
parser = fromstring(page)

links = parser.cssselect('.article-preview-item__title')
print(links)
for el in links:
    print(url + el.get('href'))
```

Заранее признателен за совет!

Comment: Если вывести `page`, то там будет тот элемент?

Comment: Действительно, по какой-то причине этих ссылок там нет. Может быть вы подскажете из-за чего страница сливается не полностью?

Comment: Думаю, в том сайте страница подгружается и/или рендерится через js. Вам нужен парсер с поддержкой js, попробуйте например selenium

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать